# Spring Data Neo4j - Cannot subclass final class class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy76

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-neo4j

I have two library projects that are dependencies for my web project. In one of the library projects I am using Spring Data JPA and the other library project I am using Spring Data Neo4j. When I try to start my web project and try to autowire my `GraphRepository` I get:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy76
```

Below are my xml files

**jpa.xml**

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.mypackage.commons" />

<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="showSql" value="true" />
    <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
    <property name="database" value="MYSQL" />
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="jdbcDataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.mypackage.commons" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" />

<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true" />
```

**neo4j.xml**

```
<neo4j:config graphDatabaseService="graphDatabaseService"
    base-package="com.mypackage.neo4j" />

<bean id="graphDatabaseService"
    class="org.springframework.data.neo4j.rest.SpringRestGraphDatabase">
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String">
            <value>http://localhost:7474/db/data/</value>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<neo4j:repositories base-package="com.mypackage.neo4j"/>
```

Comment: Would it be possible to share a sample project?

Comment: What would you need to see?

Comment: I have no idea what could be wrong, that's way I would like to have a project where I can reproduce the problem so I can try to debug it